# Assume random variable $X\sim N(\mu,\delta)$, how to evaluate $E[e^{\lambda X}]$ for all $\lambda > 0$

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation

I've tried applying *Taylor expansion* to $e^{\lambda X}$, but it seems to end up with an infinite sum of non-standard moments. Directly integrate $\int{f_X(x)e^{\lambda X}dx}$ is hard for me.

Comment: what did you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the integration, first complete the square in the exponent, expressing the integrand $f_X(x)e^{\lambda x}$ as ${1\over\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp(\lambda\mu+\lambda^2\sigma^2/2)\exp(-(x-(\mu+\lambda\sigma^2))^2/2\sigma^2)$. Factor out the first exponential, then use the fact that *any* normal density function integrates to $1$.

Comment: Completing the square is really helpful, I should have given it a try.